# Capture swipe events on Grid without ListView with scrollbar getting in the way

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I have a `Grid` that handles swipe events. On this `Grid` a `ListView` is placed. Unfortunately, if the `ListView` has its own scroll bar (bigger than the page) it "eats up" all the swipe events. It is not possible to capture swipe left or right swipe events on the parts of the screen where the `ListView` is.

The `Grid` with the `ListView`:

```
<Grid
    Name="SwipingSurface"
    Background="Transparent"
    Height="657"
    Margin="30">
   (...)
    <ListView 
        ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="True"
        Grid.Row="1"
        ItemsSource="{Binding MeditationDiary}" 
        FontFamily="Segoe WP" 
        Margin="0,45.5,0,0" 
        Grid.RowSpan="2" 
        d:LayoutOverrides="TopPosition, BottomPosition">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               [Grid and textblock template]
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

The code that handles swipe (right) events:

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

    SwipingSurface.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX | ManipulationModes.TranslateY;
    SwipingSurface.ManipulationStarted += OnStarted;
    SwipingSurface.ManipulationCompleted += OnManipulationCompleted;
}

public void OnStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _initialPoint = e.Position;
}

public void OnManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var currentPoint = e.Position;
    if (_initialPoint.X - currentPoint.X >= Constants.SwipingTreshold)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Is there a way to be able to handle swipe events on the `Grid` without the `ListView` getting in the way?

/edit Someone voted on this question since he or she found it unclear what is asked, so hereby a clarification: the code above generates the `ListView` below. It is possible to swipe left and notice the event if you swipe on `History`. But if you swipe on the `ListView` containing the content (only when it is longer than the page and you can scroll down) the swipe is not registered. I assume this is becaues the `ListView` is capturing the events.

[image: The problem with sipwing]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe adding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" to Your listView declaration could help. As an alternative You can try to modify the style of listView. Maybe you will find a scrollviewer there and then, disable it setting it property.

Comment: Thank you. Adding `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
` does not help unfortunately. I could not find anything that could change to the style of a `ScrollViewer`. I also tried:  `ManipulationMode="None"` and `ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="False"`.